# syntax error, unexpected 'mysql_connect' (T_STRING)

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need help with an error on my page using MySQL.

When I try to go to the website, this text pop up:
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'mysql_connect' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\inc\scripts\mysql_connect.inc.php on line 11`

```
<?php
$conn_error = 'Colud not connect.';

$mysql_host = "localhost:8080";
$mysql_user = "liam";
$mysql_pass = "";

$mysql_db = 'socialnetwork'


mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass or die("Couldn't Connect") ;
mysql_select_db('mysql_db') or die($conn_error);

echo 'Connected!'
?>
```

Comment: You have a missing `)` in `mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass or die("Couldn't Connect") ;` Try `mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass) or die("Couldn't Connect");`

Comment: also missing `;` in `echo 'Connected!'`

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 5):

```
$mysql_db = 'socialnetwork'
mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass or die("Couldn't Connect") ;
echo 'Connected!'
```

should be

```
$mysql_db = 'socialnetwork';
                           ^
mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass) or die("Couldn't Connect") ;
                                                   ^
echo 'Connected!';
                 ^
```

[Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 1):

here working code

```
<?php
$conn_error = 'Colud not connect.';

$mysql_host = "localhost:8080";
$mysql_user = "liam";
$mysql_pass = "";

$mysql_db = 'socialnetwork' ;
mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass) or die("Couldn't Connect") ;
mysql_select_db('mysql_db') or die($conn_error);

echo 'Connected!' ;

?>
```

you had 3 errors .

1- you forget `;` here `$mysql_db = 'socialnetwork'` .

2- you forget `)` here `mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass`.

3- you forget `;` here `echo 'Connected!'`

Comment: Thanks BUT now my site load forever i cant connect to it

Comment: it doesnt echo `'Connected!'` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your forget

> ;

here

```
$mysql_db = 'socialnetwork'
```

Comment: Oh, yeah. That, too. Ugly.....