# Could someone tell me what is causing the T_STRING error here?

Tags: php

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")
mysql_select_db("safedrive");

?>
```

I have this php file, and it wont go through.

Comment: Sorry i messed the copy paste.

Comment: Possible duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685584/unexpected-t-string-error-in-php

Comment: Why don't you use a decent editor with syntax checking?

Comment: possible duplicate of [syntax error, unexpected 'mysql\_connect' (T\_STRING)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15980597/syntax-error-unexpected-mysql-connect-t-string)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Missing semi-colon:

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") <-- HERE
mysql_select_db("safedrive");

?>
```